# Module saving/loading app settings using INI/JSON/SQLite storage format

Tags: python

This module saves/loads application settings. The application should instantiate the top API class, SettingsManager, which activates the appropriate backend (as specified or based on file extension; see BackendFormat enum). Internally, all backends store the settings in a dictionary in a unified format, permitting backend conversion. SettingsManager does not restrict direct read/write access to this data attribute, so the application can add/retrieve settings freely so long as the basic format described below is observed. An abstract base class (Backend) defines the API interface for three supported backend subclasses (provider-class/Python-module):

- INIProvider/Python-configparser;
- JSONProvider/Python-json;
- SQLiteProvider/Python-sqlite3.

Each setting element consists of triplets (section, option, value). The first two are assumed to be strings, but the latter is filtered through json.(loads|dumps) for the INI/DB backends. The JSON filter ensures appropriate Python scalar type casting and enables values of the list and dictionary types (the only permitted non-scalar types directly handled by the json module).

Note that the SQL queries are in a separate module. Also, if executed directly, this module's *demo* routine uses a dummy settings dictionary to create files in supported formats, reads the files back, and verifies that the loaded settings match the source.

**settings.py**

```py
import os
import sys
import json
from enum import Enum, unique
import configparser
import sqlite3
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeAlias

import settings_res as res


TValue: TypeAlias = int | float | str | list | dict | None
TSettings: TypeAlias = dict[str, dict[str, TValue]]


@unique
class BackendFormat(Enum):
    AUTO = ""  # Use this value for automatic format detection.
    DB = {"sqlite", "db"}  # SQLite - sqlite3
    INI = {"ini", "cfg"}  # Ini    - configparser
    JSON = {"json"}  # JSON   - json


class Backend(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, filename: str = "", create: bool = True) -> None: ...

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self) -> TSettings: ...

    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, data: TSettings) -> None: ...


def check_data_file(filename: str, create: bool = True,
                    backend: BackendFormat = BackendFormat.AUTO) -> str:
    """Performs basic checks on the data file.

    This method should verify that the provided file exists and read/write
    accessible.
    TODO: Add basic format validation methods (such as JSON format
          validation and SQLite file format validation) and call them.
          Raise FileFormatError in case of failure.
    TODO: If a specific backend format is provided with an empty file name,
          try some sane defaults (to be defined) with respect to both
          location and file name. Possibly also check if the default
          location contains a single file with an appropriate extension.

    Arguments:
        filename: Absolute or relative path to the settings data file.
        create: If True (default), creates a new file, if necessary.
                Otherwise, raises an exception.
        backend: If the filename is empty, use this for format guessing

    Returns:
        Absolute normalized path.

    Raises:
        FileNotFoundError: If create=False and the file does not exist.
        PermissionError: If read/write access is not available.
    """
    default_ext: str
    default_name: str = "settings"
    if not filename:
        if backend == BackendFormat.JSON:
            default_ext = "json"
        elif backend == BackendFormat.INI:
            default_ext = "ini"
        elif backend == BackendFormat.DB:
            default_ext = "db"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Either file name or backend must be provided.")
        filename = default_name + "." + default_ext
    filepath: str = os.path.abspath(filename)
    if not (create or os.path.isfile(filepath)):
        raise FileExistsError("Settings file is not found.")
    return filepath


def check_backend_format(backend: BackendFormat, filename: str = "") -> BackendFormat:
    """Detects backend format

    Guesses backend file format based on file extension:
        .ini | .cfg     - INI
        .json           - JSON
        .db | .sqlite   - SQLite3
    """
    if backend != BackendFormat.AUTO:
        return backend
    if not filename:
        raise ValueError("Either file name or backend must be provided.")
    ext: str = os.path.splitext(filename)[1][1:]
    backend: BackendFormat
    if ext in BackendFormat.DB.value:
        backend = BackendFormat.DB
    elif ext in BackendFormat.INI.value:
        backend = BackendFormat.INI
    elif ext in BackendFormat.JSON.value:
        backend = BackendFormat.JSON
    else:
        raise ValueError("Cannot guess settings file format.")
    return backend


class INIProvider(Backend):
    filename: str

    def __init__(self, filename: str = "", create: bool = True) -> None:
        self.filename = filename

    def load(self) -> TSettings:
        cfg: configparser.ConfigParser = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
        cfg.optionxform = lambda text: text
        cfg.read(self.filename)
        section: str
        option: str
        value: str
        data: TSettings = {}
        for section in cfg.sections():
            data[section] = {}
            for option, value in cfg.items(section):
                try:
                    data[section][option] = json.loads(value)
                except json.JSONDecodeError:
                    data[section][option] = value
        return data

    def save(self, data: TSettings) -> None:
        cfg: configparser.ConfigParser = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
        cfg.optionxform = lambda text: text
        for section in data:
            cfg[section] = {}
            for option in data[section]:
                cfg[section][option] = json.dumps(data[section][option])
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as configfile:
            cfg.write(configfile)


class JSONProvider(Backend):
    filename: str

    def __init__(self, filename: str = "", create: bool = True) -> None:
        self.filename = filename

    def load(self) -> TSettings:
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as jsonfile:
            data: TSettings = json.load(jsonfile)
        return data

    def save(self, data: TSettings) -> None:
        """Saves settings in a JSON file.

        Because json.dump saves the data as a single line, generate a custom
        human-friendly output format.
        """
        max_section: int = len(max(data.keys(), key=len))
        opt_indent: str = ' ' * (max_section + 7)
        options: list[str]
        lines: list[str] = ["{"]
        for section in data:
            lines.append(f'  "{section}": ' + ' ' * (max_section - len(section)) + '{')
            options = [
                f'{opt_indent}"{option}": {json.dumps(data[section][option])}'
                for option in data[section]
            ]
            lines.append(",\n".join(options))
            lines.append(opt_indent[:-1] + "},")
        lines[-1] = lines[-1][:-1]
        lines.append("}")
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as jsonfile:
            jsonfile.write('\n'.join(lines))


class SQLiteProvider(Backend):
    filename: str

    def __init__(self, filename: str = "", create: bool = True) -> None:
        self.filename = filename

    def load(self) -> TSettings:
        con: sqlite3.Connection = sqlite3.connect(self.filename)
        row: str
        data: TSettings = {row[0]: {} for row in con.execute(res.load_sections_sql)}
        for row in con.execute(res.load_sql):
            try:
                data[row[0]][row[1]] = json.loads(row[2])
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                data[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
        return data

    def save(self, data: TSettings) -> None:
        section: str
        option: str
        value: str
        values = []
        for section in data:
            for option in data[section]:
                values.append((section, option, json.dumps(data[section][option])))
        con: sqlite3.Connection = sqlite3.connect(self.filename)
        con.executescript(res.schema_sql)
        con.executemany(res.save_sql, values)
        con.commit()


class SettingsManager:
    """Settings manager

    This is the controller/presenter. It instantiates the model ("data") and is
    responsible for loading/persisting data.
    """

    # Settings/configuration data. Application components should
    # read/write directly
    data: TSettings
    backend: BackendFormat
    provider: Backend
    filename: str  # Normalized path to the settings data file (ini/json/db)

    def __init__(self, filename: str = "",
                 backend: BackendFormat = BackendFormat.AUTO,
                 create: bool = True) -> None:
        self.filename = check_data_file(filename, create, backend)
        self.backend = check_backend_format(backend, self.filename)
        if self.backend == BackendFormat.INI:
            self.provider = INIProvider(filename, create)
        elif self.backend == BackendFormat.JSON:
            self.provider = JSONProvider(filename, create)
        elif self.backend == BackendFormat.DB:
            self.provider = SQLiteProvider(filename, create)

    def load(self) -> None:
        self.data = self.provider.load()

    def save(self) -> None:
        self.provider.save(self.data)


def demo():
    config_data: dict = {
        "MySQL": {"version": 8.0, "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 3306, "user": "admin"},
        "HTTP": {"browser": ["firefox", "chrome", "opera"], "protocols": ["smtp", "imap"]},
        "7z": {"TypeName": "7z", "ID": "37 7A BC AF 27 1C", "IDPos": None, "Ext": "7z"}
    }

    ##### SAVE #####

    filename: str = "dummydb.json"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename)
    setman.data = config_data
    setman.save()

    filename: str = "dummydb.ini"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename)
    setman.data = config_data
    setman.save()

    filename: str = "dummydb.db"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename)
    setman.data = config_data
    setman.save()

    filename: str = "dummydb.txt"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename, BackendFormat.JSON)
    setman.data = config_data
    setman.save()

    ##### LOAD #####

    filename: str = "dummydb.ini"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename)
    setman.load()
    assert config_data == setman.data

    filename: str = "dummydb.json"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename)
    setman.load()
    assert config_data == setman.data

    filename: str = "dummydb.db"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename)
    setman.load()
    assert config_data == setman.data

    filename: str = "dummydb.txt"
    setman: SettingsManager = SettingsManager(filename, BackendFormat.JSON)
    setman.load()
    assert config_data == setman.data


def main(_argv):
    demo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

**settings_res.py**

```py
schema_sql: str = """
    BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (
        section  TEXT COLLATE NOCASE,
        option   TEXT COLLATE NOCASE,
        value,
        UNIQUE(section, option)
    );
    DELETE FROM config;
    COMMIT;
"""

save_sql = """
    INSERT INTO config(section, option, value) VALUES (:section, :option, :value);
"""

load_sql = """
    SELECT section, option, value FROM config;
"""

load_sql = """
    SELECT section, option, value FROM config;
"""

load_sections_sql = """
    SELECT DISTINCT section FROM config;
"""
```